# What is BFComponentStateException in selenium?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I got the below error message while selecting a value from a dropdown using Selenium Select in Salesforce Lightning application.

**com.salesforce.base.selenium.exceptions.BFComponentStateException: Unable to [click] [.//option[@value = "Low"]]. Component is [not visible]**

the HTML code is as below:

```
<select class="slds-input select" size="1" aria-describedby="" id="117:4743;a" data-aura-rendered-by="122:4743;a" data-interactive-lib-uid="25"><!--render facet: 123:4743;a-->
<option label="High" value="High" class="optionClass">High</option>
<option label="Low" value="Low" class="optionClass">Low</option>
<option label="Normal" value="Normal" class="optionClass">Normal</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with selenium but this sounds like a generic visibility issue. Where'd you put your script? Does this also happen with only one `option` available?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a custom SalesForce exception. Anyways as the error says its the issue of visibility, so to fix it you should put some waiting mechanism before acting on that element. Here is a function for the same that you can add :

```
 public WebElement waitForElementVisibilityByCss(String css, int timeInSeconds) {
        return (new WebDriverWait(getDriver(), timeInSeconds)).until(
                ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector(css)));
    }
```

and you can call this function for your locator. In your case call it as :

```
waitForElementVisibilityByCss("[label='Low']",30)
```

Try and let us know if it works.

Comment: The dropdown element is visible and also other elements of the same page is also been accessed. Textbox are working properly but don't know why the dropdown is not working.

Comment: It could be visible when you are checking it manually. But script might see it in different way, thats why we put waits to handle such synchronisation issues in locator loading and visibility.